# Azure Devops Server 2019 limits select in expand to 8 columns

Tags: azure-devops, odata, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-analytics

Is there a way to change this limit on the server? 2020 does not seem to have this limit. Or potentially is there a better way to write the expand clause that will result in less columns? I need all the data here to produce my report.

`...$select=WorkItemId,Title,WorkItemType,StartDate,TargetDate,State,StateCategory,IterationSK&$expand=Iteration($select=StartDate,EndDate),Project,Descendants($apply=filter(WorkItemType in ('Feature','User Story','Task','Bug') and ProjectSK eq XXXXXXX and State ne 'Removed');$select=Title,WorkItemId,WorkItemType,State,StartDate,TargetDate,ParentWorkItemId,OriginalEstimate,StoryPoints;$expand=Iteration($select=IterationSK,StartDate,EndDate))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $expand on the `Children` rather than `Descendants` to [return information about an item's Children](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/extend-analytics/work-item-links?view=azure-devops-2019#example-parent-to-child-query). I got the same errror `limit of 8 columns` when i used `Descendants`. The error was gone if i changed to `Children`

See below:
Change `Descendants` to `Children`

```
$select=WorkItemId,Title,WorkItemType,StartDate,TargetDate,State,StateCategory,IterationSK&$expand=Iteration($select=StartDate,EndDate),Project,Children($apply=filter(WorkItemType in ('Feature','User Story','Task','Bug') and ProjectSK eq XXXXXXX and State ne 'Removed');$select=Title,WorkItemId,WorkItemType,State,StartDate,TargetDate,ParentWorkItemId,OriginalEstimate,StoryPoints;$expand=Iteration($select=IterationSK,StartDate,EndDate))
```

Comment: children is only one level deep though. I need the entire tree of items that are below a given Epic.

Comment: @MatthewTheTerrible I am afraid the limitation to 8 columns for azure deveps 2019 server is by design. You probably need to upgrade to [azure devops 2020](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/get-started?view=azure-devops-2020), or you can use `Children` and re-construct the return result using codes as workaround.  You can also report this issue to [Microsoft Development team](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/report?entry=problem&space=22).

Comment: Is their an API available that I can use to determine what version of ADO the user is on so that I can construct queries dynamically.

Comment: @MatthewTheTerrible There is not an api available to get the version. But you can make http request to this url `https://tfs2019:port/my_collection/_home/about ` to get the version details. Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60121094/how-does-azure-devops-service-version-is-determined).