# Availability of wildcards in path filters in YAML pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, build-triggers

According to a recent update here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-192-update#support-for-wild-cards-in-path-filters wildcards will be supported in path triggers in 2-3 weeks (Presumably from the date of the document September the 8th).

Is there any way that we can check the availability of this? It doesn't seem to work but we are left wondering if the release was delayed and the docs not updated or if we are doing something wrong.

As a very simple example I'd expect the below to trigger a build when something changes in the src directory, but nothing happens - Have I made a mistake or has the update not been rolled out yet?

```
trigger:
 branches:
   include:
     - main
     - develop
 paths:
  include:
    - src/**
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60121094/how-is-the-azure-devops-service-version-determined gives a way to check what version is being used maybe?  Presumably if the date of the build is later than september 8th it should work?  (Note I haven't checked this myself, so I can't confirm if wildcard path filters work or not for me.)

Comment: That makes sense, Just checked and we're on a build from 30th September which is *just* outside the 3 week window that was mentioned in the docs. Guess Ill do some more digging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, this was an issue with the timing.

The MS docs had been updated suggesting that the feature was available however the deployment had been delayed so the feature was not available in our region.

This is now resolved and the feature is available to us now.